# Matching two imageBox controls (EmguCV)

Tags: c#, emgucv

Currently I'm working with a fingerletter recognition using visual studio 2013 C# along with emguCV. i already have a database using ms access and a program which allow me to add images(in graysacle already) to it.

- I've got 2 imageBox (imageBox0, imageBox1, imageBox2).., imageBox0 displays the live streaming of my camera., imageBox1 displays the processed image of imageBox0 (contour of my hand, grayscale, rectangle) and imageBox2 displays a selected image from the ms access database.

What I needed is a way to recognize an image from imageBox1 that is similar to imageBox2 or (in the whole images inside the database)

Here are snapshots of what I am doing:

[image]

I am using EmguCV version 2.

```
private Image GetImgFromDB() 
{   
    if (rowNumber >= 0)
    {   
        byte[] FetchedImgBytes = (byte[])LocalDataTable.Rows[rowNumber]["alphaImage"];
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(FetchedImgBytes);
        FetchedImg = Image.FromStream(stream);
        txtAlphaName.Text = (string)LocalDataTable.Rows[rowNumber]["AlphaName"];

         Bitmap FetchedImgCV = (Bitmap)FetchedImg;
         normalizedMasterImage = new Image<Gray, Byte>(FetchedImgCV);

        return FetchedImg; 
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("There are no images in the dataase yet. add some Please");
        //return null;
    }
    return null; 
} `
```

Answer (score 1):

I've been though this with quiet a good degree of success. Mine compares two images and you set the percentage differences between to two to raise an alert.

The key is to compare hashes, not raw data...

```
class bitmapCompare
{
    public enum CompareResult
    {
        ciCompareOk,
        ciPixelMismatch,
        ciSizeMismatch
    };

    public static CompareResult Compare(bool useHash, Bitmap bmp1, Bitmap bmp2, out double err, out Bitmap diff)
    {
        CompareResult cr = CompareResult.ciCompareOk;
        int er = 0;
        err = 0;
        diff = new Bitmap(bmp1.Width, bmp1.Height);
        //Test to see if we have the same size of image

        if (bmp1.Size != bmp2.Size)
        {
            cr = CompareResult.ciSizeMismatch;
            err = 100;
        }
        else
        {
            //Convert each image to a byte array

            System.Drawing.ImageConverter ic =
                   new System.Drawing.ImageConverter();
            byte[] btImage1 = new byte[1];
            btImage1 = (byte[])ic.ConvertTo(bmp1, btImage1.GetType());
            byte[] btImage2 = new byte[1];
            btImage2 = (byte[])ic.ConvertTo(bmp2, btImage2.GetType());

            //Compute a hash for each image

            SHA256Managed shaM = new SHA256Managed();
            byte[] hash1 = shaM.ComputeHash(btImage1);
            byte[] hash2 = shaM.ComputeHash(btImage2);

            //Compare the hash values
            if (useHash)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < hash1.Length && i < hash2.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (hash1[i] != hash2[i])
                    {
                        er++;
                        cr = CompareResult.ciPixelMismatch;
                    }
                }

            }
            else
            {
                int totalPixels = 0;
                er = 0;
                for (int x = 0; x < bmp1.Width; x++)
                {
                    for (int y = 0; y < bmp1.Height; y++)
                    {
                        totalPixels++;
                        if (bmp1.GetPixel(x, y) != bmp2.GetPixel(x, y))
                        {


                            diff.SetPixel(x, y, Color.Black);
                            er++;
                            cr = CompareResult.ciPixelMismatch;
                        }
                        else
                            diff.SetPixel(x, y, Color.White);
                    }
                }
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Total pixels:{0}", totalPixels);
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Diff pixels:{0}", er);

                if (er > 0)
                    err = (double)er / ((double)bmp1.Height * (double)bmp1.Width);
                else
                    err = 0;
                if (err > 0) err = Math.Round(err*100, 1);
                if (err > 100) err = 100;


            }
        }
        return cr;
    }
```

Feel free to change, this was only a POC, nothing production.

Comment: i'll look at it bro., thanks a lot.
hope i can figure out something and finish my work..

Comment: Actually, after viewing the code, the hash will give you a fast "Do they match, yes or no?" but the non-hash will compare, and generate a compare bitmap, highlighting the areas different.

I used this to compare Selenium screen dumps to cut down on false positives. Any problems, ping me.

Comment: bro, can you help me please how would i utilize your code with mine (how would i use it to compare imageBox1 and imageBox2)..,

also., does my understanding with this one correct?... 



`SHA256Managed shaM = new SHA256Managed(); //namespace of the main program?

                byte[] hash1 = shaM.ComputeHash(btImage1); //btImage1 = name of the imageBox1(emguCV)

                byte[] hash2 = shaM.ComputeHash(btImage2);//btImage2 = name of the imageBox(emguCV) `
thanks once again...

Comment: I've push my POC to a GIT repo.

https://github.com/MilesHart/WebImageCompare

Set the WebCheckerPOC project as startup. Enter a URL and get two thumbnails, then click on each and it should start comparing....